# Can different strains of Rhizobium share an infection thread or symbiosome?

Tags: bacteriology, plant-physiology, ecology, infection, agriculture

Rhizobium infection can be triggered at root hairs of legumes, creating infection threads.

Can these infections threads be colonized by more than one type of Rhizobium (e.g. Fixing and non-fixing)?

What about when the infection is inside the plant cells? Can symbiosomes be co-inhabited by different bacteria?